# Ionic 4 create project in a directory

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I have a folder name `hybridapp` inside Projects folder. I want to create a new Ionic project inside the folder `hybridapp` and don't want Ionic to create any new root project folder.

Right now, ionic start . is interpreted as "create a project named .".

```
$ mkdir project; cd project
$ ionic start .
Please name your Ionic project something meaningful other than '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one way to create new Ionic4 project in a specific way as follows:

1. Move out of your the project folder i.e. in my case `hybridapp`.
2. Then create a new Ionic project using `Ionic start` but give the App name same as your project folder app i.e. `hybridapp` in my case.

`ionic start hybridapp`

Now when we move inside the project folder we can see all the Ionic files generated by Ionic.
[image]